# Using transform: origin to center an element

Tags: html, css

I've rotated a simple paragraph. I'm trying to get it aligned to the to the left of the browser by `0%` and the from the top of the browser `50%`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/fyYS7/

```
p {
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

}
```

I would do `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%`, but the rotate seems to totally skew those attributes.

[I've tried reading these docs, but I'm quite confused.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Answer (score 0):

`transform-origin` will give the point where the element is'nailed' in order to transform it.when you say `left center` , it nails the element in its vertical middle and at left,  transform starts from there, so transform will obviously hide part of it as soon as it rotates.

What you want is to drop it from top and left. Once rotation is given, you can use translate, to slide it back in view.
http://jsfiddle.net/fyYS7/1/

```
p {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translatex(-100%);
}
```